# Python not seeing packages after pip install

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

When I run the following command within my virtual env

> sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt

It says that the packages were successfully installed, but when I try to run or import the packages, it can not find them.

pip3 show  returns nothing.

However, when I manually run

> sudo pip3 install package-name

It installs the package just fine and it works.

Why is pip install -r requirements.txt not working? It always worked in the past. Now that I reinstalled Python it stopped working..

**System:**
Ubuntu 14.04
Python changed from 3.4 to 3.6.2

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==2.0.8

django-debug-toolbar

channels
```

**Debugging in Terminal:**

EDIT: This makes no sense.

> pip3 install -r requirements.txt

```
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.7->autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.3->channels==2.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 79)) (2.19)
```

> $ pip3 --version

```
pip 19.2.3 from /home/dominic/Desktop/projects/printrender/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I install packages in my Virtual Environemnt using pip3 install -r requirements and it says that they are already installed, but when I run Pip Freeze, it returns nothing, as if nothing is installed.

Pip3 install -r requirements is placing my packages in my local packages python packages, and pip freeze is referencing my virtual env packages.

pip is not installing this packages in the correct place

Comment: Try using [`virtualenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) - it saves so many pathing headaches.

Comment: whats your current folder when you are running pip3 install -r requirements.txt? Can you try python -m pip install -r requirements.txt?

Comment: I'm using Virtualenv and yes I am in the correct folder when I run pip3 install -r requirements.txt. The problem has something to do with pip or virtualenv using different python paths. It must be..

Comment: Never ever use `sudo pip`.

Comment: Use `venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` then `venv/bin/python` to run your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use `sudo` when you're using a virtual environment. Try without.

Answer (score 0):

I think you created a virtual environment for python 2 by mistake since `pip3` is used from `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` instead of in the `env`. You can create the virtual environment specifically for python3 by using the command

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

Could you try creating a new virtual environment with the command above and see if it works?

Comment: I am using that exact command, I think my virtualenv is using the wrong path. its using 
    /usr/bin/python3

Comment: Could you try the command `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` when activating the virtual environment to see if it outputs the correct path?

Comment: Or if not it could be that `virtualenv` is outdated so it doesn't behave correctly. Do you know which version it is currently running on? Maybe updating it to the latest version?

Comment: echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
/home/dominic/Desktop/projects/printrender/env

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (16.7.5)

Comment: my virtualenv pip freeze is the same as when I'm not in my virtualenv. My virtualenv is pulling the packages from my local packages, not the virtualenv packages. How do I fix this

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Maybe the python scripts is messing up the virtual environment? Can you try creating a new environment, activate it and check if the python3, pip3 paths are inside that new environment but don't run the `local.py` script?

Comment: Pip install -r requirements is placing the packages in my usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages, but pip freeze is referencing my virtualenv site-packages. This is so confusing.

Comment: Did you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with sudo? I don't think pip can place the packages in `/usr/lib` without root privilege. I don't think using sudo for pip install is needed when using virtualenv.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using sudo pip install -r requirements and it returns that all packages are satisified, but pip freeze returns no packages. Both commands ran inside virtualenv

Comment: Could you try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` again without sudo inside the virtualenv? I think `sudo` is what causing the path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using sudo was part of the issue and some of the packages in my requirements.txt were causing errors with the latest version of pip.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sudo`, you installed your packages globally. This must solve your problem.

```
sudo su
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```